# What is the use to serve favicon from server

Tags: node.js

I have a doubt regarding `favicon`, I can add `favicon` directly in `html` file itself with following code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I have tried with above code, it's working fine. I have seen there are some modules in `npm` to server `favicon` images. If I add through `html`, why I have to use this modules to serve.

Comment: What this html code have to do with **serving** favicon? It's telling your browser where to find it, but your server should serve it.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny why my server should serve this, If I can handle with html code. If I server through my server,is there any use. As of I know, `favicon` only for design purpose. Or is there any reason.

Comment: Phrase "to serve" means "to provide content". So, "serving `favicon.ico`" means that your server will return `favicon.ico` content when `/favicon.ico` url is requested. There are many ways to serve it. For example, you could mount your static folder to `/` and put `favicon.ico` file there. But serving is what servers do.

Comment: By the way, you said that your html code is working. Does it mean that you can see your `favicon.ico` in browser? If so, then you're already serving `favicon.ico` from your server.

Comment: Through `html`, I can able to see `favicon.ico`. My html file serving by server, but `favicon` serving by html file. This is what serving `favicon` through html. But when you serve through server, you no need to do anything in html file. That means, directly server serving the `favicon.ico`.

Comment: But do you actually see a favicon image? You could have a shortcut icon link in your html, but it doesn't mean that you're really serving it.

Answer (score 4):

For the case of [serve-favicon](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) module:

**Why use this module?**

- User agents request favicon.ico frequently and indiscriminately, so
  you may wish to exclude these requests from your logs by using this
  middleware before your logger middleware.
- This module caches the icon
  in memory to improve performance by skipping disk access.
- This module
  provides an ETag based on the contents of the icon, rather than file
  system properties.
- This module will serve with the most compatible
  Content-Type.